# Running a script on NuGet Package Manager Console

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget

I'm using the MvcScaffolding NuGet Package to scaffold a couple of Controllers. I'm currently repeating the same process ie. `Scaffold Controller MyController -Repository -Force`. I do this for a number of controllers. Is there a way to run a script on the console where I can put a couple of commands and run them once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a Powershell noob, so there may be a better way, but I just ran this in the Package Manager Console:

```
$controllers = "test", "test2"; foreach ($controller in $controllers) { echo $controller }
```

And it seemed to work, so maybe something like this would work?

```
$controllers = "test", "test2"; foreach ($controller in $controllers) { Scaffold Controller $controller -Repository -Force }
```

Comment: Stranger things have happened ;)